# How To Print @ OR { in view page in asp.net mvc project using razor viewengine?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

if we have a c# code between view page and wants to print string with `@` or `{` between string .how it is possible in view page.

EXample-

```
@if(rules)
{

/////////////print something here with @ and {//////

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in `<text>` tags.

```
<text>test@test.com</text>
```

Answer (score 6):

@@ is the escape character for @ in Razor views

Answer (score 2):

`@@` is the way doing it in MVC Razor